# How to sum a column formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, multiplication

I have this Excel sheet in which I have many columns, and I need a sum formula applied to every one of them:

```
|   |    A      |   B   |    C  |   D   |     E    |
| 1 | Products  | Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 | Revenues | 
| 2 | Price/u   |  10   |   20  |  30   | -------- |
| 3 |Price Fixed|   5   |   10  |   2   | -------- |
| 4 |Sales      | ----- | ----- | ----- | -------- |
| 5 |   2017    |   1   |  5    |  56   |  ??????  |
| 6 |   2018    |  3    |   10  |  100  |  ??????  |
| 7 | -------------------------------------------- |
| 8 |   TOTAL   | SUM() | SUM() | SUM() | -------- |
```

I was wondering how to calculate `?????`. Indeed, it would look like:
`=(B5 * B2 + B3) + (C5 * C2 + C3) + (D5 * D2 + D3)`, the problem is that I need to get that to `Z`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B5:Z5*B2:Z2 + B3:Z3)
```

`SUMPRODUCT` operates on arrays. It is here submitted a single array, so it just sums it up. This array is computed as:

- element-wise product of the row vectors B5:Z5*B2:Z2
- element-wise addition of row vector B3:Z3

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an array formula and then sum the lot:

`={SUM(B5:Z5*B2:Z2+B3:Z3)}` not forgetting to do array formulae you use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER